# How to load our own java file in VM image preconfigured with hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, virtual-machine

I am new to Hadoop Environment. To play around samples and to get to know about it I have installed a preconfigured VM with Hadoop environment from [Here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vm)

I can run the samples provided in hadoop. I need to load my data in the VM and have to run it using hadoop. But i don't know how to do it since the VM has no GUI and only command line options.

I am using Windows 7. I would appreciate it if anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have installed a Hadoop VM, you must have an IP to the VM. Since you are using Windows, install the software [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) and connect to your VM using its IP. Then copy the files you want to from your windows machine to the VM's filesystem. You can then copy the files from the VM's file system using the command:

```
hadoop fs -put <file_in_vm_file_system> <location_in_hdfs>
```

Hope this helps.